# PHP file redirects/leaves main page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

In my PHP code, I just want to connect to MySql database, then check for length values, but when I do this, it redirects the page to the PHP file. How can I show the alerts only through the main page?

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "abc123";
$dbname = "redstonegaming";
$ip = get_client_ip();
$datetime = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
$temp1 = $_GET["name"];
$temp2 = $_GET["comment"];
$comment = "";
$commentname = "";
if (strlen($temp1) < 1)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Your message must be more than 0 characters!');</script>";
}

else if (strlen($temp2) > 300)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Your message must be less than 300 characters!');</script>";
}
else {
    send();
}

function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress =  getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    echo "<script>alert('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);</script>";
} 

function send() 
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments(Name, Message, Ip_Address, dateTime) VALUES ('$commentname','$comment','$ip','$datetime')";
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
    echo "<script>alert('New Record Created Successfully!');</script>";
} 
else 
{
    echo "<script>alert('Error: ' . $sql . '<br>' . $conn->error');</script>";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

```js
var rick = false;
var audio = new Audio('rick_roll.mp3');
var kkeys = [],
  konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65,13";
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  kkeys.push(e.keyCode);
  if (kkeys.toString().indexOf(konami) >= 0) {
    kkeys = []; // <-- Change here
    if (rick == false) {
      rick = true;
      audio.play();
    } else if (rick == true) {
      rick = false;
      audio.pause(); // <-- another issue
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/*Some Fonts Here:*/
@font-face { font-family: Rusty; src: url('BrushScriptStd.otf');}
* {
 font-family: Rusty;
 font-weight: Lighter;
}
.background
{
 background-image: url(0.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-color: f7f7f7;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:absolute;
}
.menubar {
  position: relative;
  height: 2.8vw;
  opacity: 0.85;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  z-index: 1;
}
.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.menu-wrap {
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #3e3436;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Ek Mukta';
}
.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: #919191;
}
.menu li:hover > a,
.menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 0.95vw;
  line-height: 0%;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  float: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 0.7vw 5vh;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a,
.menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background: #2e2728;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  transition: opacity linear 5.8s;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #2e2728;
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #3e3436;
}
.Rusty 
{
 font-family: "Rusty";
 color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
 display: inline;
}
.content
{
 opacity: .85;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
 z-index: 0; 
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 10px;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.menu > ul > .login 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.video-container {
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom: 5%;
 padding-top: 30px;
 width: 100%;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
 position: relative;
 top:15%;
 width: 27vw;
 height:27vh;
}
.title
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 7vh;
 text-decoration: underline;
 -moz-text-decoration-color: inherit;
    text-decoration-color: inherit;
}
.feed-column
{
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
}
.border-right
{
 border-right: thick solid rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.text-center
{
 text-align: center;
}
.footer
{
    background: #CCCCCC;
 position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
 opacity: .85;
}
.yt-title
{
 font-size: 3.3vh;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-subscribe-widget-webp-vflj9zwo0.css"
    name="www-subscribe-widget" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>RG - Home</title>
    <style>
#comment_form input, #comment_form textarea {
        border: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        padding: 8px 10px;
        
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        
        outline: 0;
}

#comment_form textarea {
        width: 350px;
}

#comment_form input[type=&quot;submit&quot;] {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #ddd);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #ddd);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #ddd);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #ddd);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #ddd);
        color: #333;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#comment_form input[type=&quot;submit&quot;]:hover {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

#comment_form input[type=&quot;submit&quot;]:active {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ddd, #aaa);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ddd, #aaa);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ddd, #aaa);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ddd, #aaa);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #ddd, #aaa);   
        border: 1px solid #999;
}
.align-middle
{
position: absolute;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <div class="menubar">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li>
            <a href="aboutme.html">About Me 
            <span class="arrow">▼</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Gaming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Programming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">YouTube</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Other</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
          </li>
          <li class="current-item">
            <a href="#">
              <img style="width: 2.3vh; height: 1.6vw;" align="left" src="favicon.ico" />
              <p align="middle" class="rusty">RedstoneGaming</p>
              <img style="width: 2.3vh; height: 1.6vw;" align="right" src="favicon.ico" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="equipment.html">Equipment</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
          <li class="login">
            <a href="login.html">Login/Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="rusty title">RedstoneGaming Comments</h1>
      <div class="border-right feed-column align-middle">
        <div id="comment_form">
          <form action="welcome.php" method="get">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" /> 
          <textarea rows="10" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Enter your message here"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Comment" /></form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="feed-column"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">vv</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Submitting a form reloads the page with the contents of the `action` script. If you don't want to do that, you need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include **action=""** tag in form.
So when you press submit, script doesn't know where to execute.

Fix it by

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="get" action="">
```

And most easiest solution for your problem is to include that PHP script into top of HTML document with empty **action=""** tag. It will look up for php script on that page.

Note it is a bad practice. If you are using some other page in action tag, make sure you add header() function in PHP to redirect (somewhere if needed).

And one more notice.
Your function send() will not execute SQL, it basicaly just storing sql statement in variable.

Hope it helps,